How to update a parameter value when an Azure pipeline in another project is successful
I have to update parameter values based on whether the xyz pipeline in project pqr is successful or  pipeline abc in project pqr is successful.
That is
pipeline successful   parameter value
    abc                aaa
    xyz                zzz

I am trying the below code in my pipeline but not successful
  # Define parameters parameters: 
  - name: newrel 
    displayName: "Release Version (semver)" 
    type: string 
  - name: component 
    displayName: "Component Directory" 
    type: string 
    default: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\abc' 
    resources: 
    pipelines: 
     - pipeline: A_Pipeline 
       source: abc 
       project: pqr 
       trigger: 
       branches: 
       include: - '*' 
       - pipeline: B_Pipeline 
         source: xyz 
         project: pqr 
         trigger: 
           branches: 
             include: - '*'

Powershell:
    if ('$(pqr.abc.result)' -eq 'succeeded') {
        Write-Host "abc in pqr succeeded"
        Write-Host "Setting component directory to aaa"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\aaa"
    }
    elseif ('$(pqr.xyz.result)' -eq 'succeeded') 
    {
        Write-Host "xyz in pqr succeeded"
        Write-Host "Setting component directory to zzz"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\zzz"
    }


Define parameters
parameters:

name: newrel
displayName: "Release Version (semver)"
type: string
name: component
displayName: "Component Directory"
type: string
default: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\abc'
resources:
pipelines:
pipeline: A_Pipeline
source: abc
project: pqr
trigger:
branches:
include:
- '*'
pipeline: B_Pipeline
source: xyz
project: pqr
trigger:
branches:
include:
- '*'
#followed by the above code


The pipeline as the resource will trigger the current pipeline only if it runs successfully. Therefore, there is no need to use the result of your resource pipeline in the condition. You can use pipeline resource variables Resources.TriggeringAlias to set the value of component based on which resource pipeline triggered the pipeline. Refer to the example below.
trigger:
- none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: xyz # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: xyz # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: pqr
    trigger: true
  - pipeline: abc # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: abc # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: pqr
    trigger: true

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if ('$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)' -eq 'abc') {
          Write-Host "abc in pqr succeeded"
          Write-Host "Setting component directory to aaa"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\aaa"
      }
      elseif ('$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)' -eq 'xyz') 
      {
          Write-Host "xyz in pqr succeeded"
          Write-Host "Setting component directory to zzz"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\assets\zzz"
      }

You define component as a parameter, but parameter does not support updating its value during runtime. You can directly use the above PowerShell scripts to create an output variable component and use it with $(component) in subsequent steps.

You define component as a parameter, but parameter does not support updating its value during runtime. You can directly use the above PowerShell scripts to create an output variable component and use it with $(component) in subsequent steps.
I have defined a variable
variables:
component: "kvi"

I have defined a variable variables: component: "kvi" But the script jobs: - job: DetermineComponentDirectory displayName: "Determine Component Directory" steps: - powershell: | if ("$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)" -eq "abc") { Write-Host "abc Pipeline in pqr succeeded" Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component;isOutput=true]$(sdf)" } is not updating the component variable

Logging command task.setvariable is used to create an output variable. It can't update the value of variables defined by you. Even though they have the same name, they are actually two independent variables.
